Как осуществить аутентификацию в laravel через WhatsApp?
Есть проблема с реализацией аутентификации и авторизации в laravel 10 через сервис WhatsApp. Есть ли где-то официальная информация или хороший пример, статья, как реализовать такой механизм? Искал в интернете, не нашел путной конкретной информации. Спасибо, за ответы и советы.

А конкретнее, в чем именно проблема? Какие ресурсы были изучены и почему они не подошли? У Laravel есть прослойка (middleware) в которой можно реализовать всё что угодно, включая аутентификацию и авторизацию. Каков требуемый итог, ТЗ?

@DanielProtopopov, в этой статье я изложил, как сделать авторизацию через телеграмм https://love-nord.ru/index.php?url=detail_blog&id=577, однако, в предложенных провайдерах для социальных сетей я не нашел whatsapp https://socialiteproviders.com/about. Список там представлен слева. Потому как бы понимаю, что реализация через oauth2 через whatsapp невозможна.

У WhatsApp нет OAuth механизма авторизации, там нужно создавать токен для приложения WhatsApp, и затем его использовать.

@DanielProtopopov, в свете того, что я описал, проект на ларавел без участия каких-либо социальных сетей, где создавать токен? Если ли у вас пример реализации?

Я привел ссылку на документацию, в которой описано как создавать токен чтобы использовать его для отсылки сообщений, например. О какой реализации идет речь, если мы уже выяснили что нет авторизации и аутентификации, кроме как через токен?
